# Please remove the limits on user access to the schematic tool

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, schematic

I'm in a discussion with a user who doesn't seem to have access to the schematic tool. Is there a "reputation threshold" for access to this tool? If so, can we get rid of them?

Comment: WRT that question, I think you did a good job with the edit but it is not really necessary to ask people to add a schematic if they have something that more or less amounts to the same thing in context, such as a fritzing diagram.

Comment: @goldilocks: My memory (and vision) may have failed me, but I recall the fritzing diagram was added in an edit by the OP after I made a comment about the snapshot he included initially. That said, I don't always find fritzing diagrams entirely clear - but that's just me.

Comment: I'm afraid some failure there was -- I did in fact think to check if you prompted the OP to do that, but such is not the case.  You can [view the revision history of a question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/89082/revisions) by clicking "edited [some time qualifier]" underneath the question body,  right above the icon of whoever is responsible for the last edit . Note that is distinct from the "edit" button above it to the left.  There's also a little circular arrow/clock thing under the lefthand scoreboard that reveals a timeline of events for the question.

Comment: ...Anyway, the first version of that one includes the fritizing diagram and I think your initial comment references that too ("consider using the schematic tool *instead of wiring graphics*").

Comment: @goldilocks: Perhaps there was failure, but help me sort out whose it was. There were two questions re. schematics: 1. [RPi.GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89044/rpi-gpio-properly-wiring-and-setting-up-pins-for-button-inputs) and 2. [Powering a sensor](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89082/powering-a-sensor-using-an-external-power-supply-board) . My (meta) question concerned the former (1., not 2.), and for Q 1. the _fritzing-like_ diagram was added to that question approximately 24 hours after my comment.  CONTINUED BELOW

Comment: So when you said, "WRT that question...", you have picked up a different question than the one I was asking about. Now as far as Q 2., I said (emphasis added), "My only suggestion is that you **consider** using the schematic tool instead of wiring graphics to show your wiring. It's **actually not essential in this case, as your wiring is fairly clear**, but please know that the tool is available, and that it will have distinct advantages in some cases." Can you tell me how you get that I asked him to add a schematic?

Comment: I stand corrected!

Comment: @seamus, *I don't always find fritzing diagrams entirely clear - but that's just me*. I like that, it's the great grandmother of understatement... And no, it's not just you ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there is, although it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere. If you view the site logged out (as an unregistered user) the schematic button doesn't appear on the question or answer form, so at the very least unregistered users can't.

I'm guessing (although haven't tested) that the level is [11 rep](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2728/133451), because this was the original threshold on the [Electronics site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) (which got schematics first). Since then, the threshold has been removed there—but apparently it remains here.

If you take a look at Electronics as an unregistered user, the schematic button *does* appear, so it looks like it should be possible to have it changed if desired.

Comment: Realistically, this would account for so little additional use it might as well be done.  I'll see if I can get Ghanima to lay on the charm somewhere...

Comment: Well, I do now feel a bit of an arse for telling a new contributor to improve his question by using a schematic instead of a snapshot of "wiring spaghetti". It also seems to run counter to the attitudes now being cultivated in SE regarding new users; i.e. does it make you feel welcome if you're told you can't use the tools? That's just my £0.02. Is there anything I can do to move this toward change?

Comment: By the same reasoning, it might make you feel unwelcome to be told you can't comment indiscriminately on the site until you reach a certain rep threshold, you can't vote, you can't create tags, etc.  But "be welcoming" doesn't mean invite someone to burn your house down if they like. It is perfectly reasonable when you are in a home you've never been in before to respect various implicit and explicit rules ("Don't swear around my kids",  stay out of the bedrooms, etc.).  In this case I agree it should be allowed because I don't see how being able to use the schematic editor could be abused.